# How to filter binary image with unwanted region and hole region

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I have a hard problem that need your help. I have a binary image that maintains some unwanted region (small white dot) and hole regions (in figure 1).My idea is that the first I will remove unwanted region by calculating area these region and then filter with small area value.At the second step, I fill in hole region to make clear image.What do you think best method to fill in hole region. Do you have any idea to resolve it. Could you help me implement it by matlab. Thank you so much. This is my reference code for remove unwanted region. But it need threshold term. You can download image test at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvodekty93scckm/input.mat)

```
function exImage=rmUnwantedRegion(Img,threshold)
    lb = bwlabel(Img);
    st = regionprops(lb, 'Area', 'PixelIdxList' );
    toRemove = [st.Area] <threshold; % fix your threshold here
    exImage = Img;
    exImage( vertcat(st(toRemove).PixelIdxList ) ) = 0; % remove
 end
```

[image]

Comment: Try `exImage = bwareaopen(Img, threshold)`.

Comment: @Jigg: bwareopen needs threshold value. It does not stable. I think convolution scheme is good.

Comment: Upload your original image, people will be able to test their proposals.

Comment: @Jigg: Please check again. I uploaded it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example implementation based on my comment:

```
subplot(1,3,1), imshow(input);
title('Original Image');
```

Calculating the opening of the image:

```
openInput=bwareaopen(input, 20);    
subplot(1,3,2), imshow(bwareaopen(input, 20));
title('Opened Image');
```

And the subsequent closing:

```
ClosedInput = imclose(openInput,ones(10)); 
subplot(1,3,3), imshow(ClosedInput);
title('Closed Image');
```

Result:

[image: Morph filtered image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming white pixel is 1
Black is 0
Step 1:
Use convultion matrix (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29)

with blur filter

Step 2:
Treshold each pixel with some static value (for example 0.5)

if pixel is >0.5 pixel = 1
  else pixel = 0

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for binary [dilation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) and [erosion](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html). Generally an erosion is done first to remove unwanted noise and then dilation is performed with the same structuring element to fill in the gaps left by the erosion. Matlab uses [strel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel.html) to create structuring elements for morphological operations. You can also read about morphological operators [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology)

Example:

```
SE=strel('square',5);
im_eroded=imerode(im,SE);
im_dilated=imdilate(im_eroded,SE);
```

Comment: I applied morphological but its result is very bad. I used SE=strel('square',2);

Comment: Choice of structuring element is critical as it can become apparent if the dilation is extreme. Try a disk structuring element. You can also use two different SE's if the holes and noise are different sizes.

Answer (score -3):

You need to do an erosion ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_%28morphology%29) or [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html)) followed by a dilation ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_%28morphology%29) or [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html)). This is done using the *imerode* and the *imdilate* functions in Matlab.

Doing this require to specify the size of the element eroding and dilating using the [strel function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel.html) with a shape ('square', 'disk', 'octagon', etc.) and a size.

```
SE=strel('disk',5);
im_eroded=imerode(im,SE);
im_dilated=imdilate(im_eroded,SE);
```

Comment: 'circle' is not available in matlab

Comment: This is an almost exact duplicate of @Raab70 answer above. Please upvote answers and add links in comments instead of duplicating them.